# Ampscript for dynamic table rows using Lookup rows

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am doing a look up rows and then using IF THEN to determine the number of rows that should populate in the table.

After the lookup,
IF **DE** row is as below

[image]

THEN **output** should be

[image]

IF **DE** is as below (see second row)

[image]

THEN **output** should be

[image]

IF **DE** is as below (third row)

[image]

THEN **output** should be

[image]

**My code**

```
%%[ var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @numRowsToReturn, @lookupValue, @i, 
set @lookupValue = AttributeValue("Name") 
set @numRowsToReturn = 0 set @rows = LookupOrderedRows("SalesforceApplication_Website",@numRowsToReturn,"Monthly_Charge__c asc, Mobile_Calling_Charge__c asc, International_Calling_Charge__c asc","Name", @lookupValue) ]%%
%%[ 
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows) if @rowCount > 0 then
for @i = 1 to @rowCount do 
set @row = row(@rows,@i) 
set @Product = field(@row,"Energy_Type__c")  ]%%
%%[ IF @Product == "Voice" THEN 
set @Monthly_Charge__c = field(@row,"Monthly_Charge__c") 
set @Mobile_Calling_Charge__c = field(@row,"Mobile_Calling_Charge__c") 
set @International_Calling_Charge__c = field(@row,"International_Calling_Charge__c") Endif ]%%
<table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="10" dir="ltr" style="width:600px;" width="90%">  
  %%[ if empty(@Mobile_Calling_Charge__c) and empty(@International_Calling_Charge__c) then ]%%
  <tr>
    <td width="50%">
      <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
        <span style="font-size: 14px;"><b>Monthly charge
          </b></span>
      </font>
    </td>
    <td width="50%">
      <span style="font-size:14px;"><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;">$%%=v(@Monthly_Charge__c)=%%</span></span>
    </td>
  </tr> %%[ endif ]%%    
  %%[ if NOT empty(@Mobile_Calling_Charge__c) and empty(@International_Calling_Charge__c) then ]%%
  <tr>
    <td width="50%">
      <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
        <span style="font-size: 14px;"><b>Monthly charge
          </b></span>
      </font>
    </td>
    <td width="50%">
      <span style="font-size:14px;"><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;">$%%=v(@Monthly_Charge__c)=%%</span></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="50%">
      <b>
        <span style="font-size:14px;"><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;">Mobile calling charge</span></span>
      </b>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span style="font-size:14px;"><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;">$%%=v(@Mobile_Calling_Charge__c)=%%</span></span>
    </td>
  </tr> %%[ endif ]%%      
  %%[ if empty(@Mobile_Calling_Charge__c) and not empty(@International_Calling_Charge__c) then ]%%
  <tr>
    <td width="50%">
      <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
        <span style="font-size: 14px;"><b>Monthly charge
          </b></span>
      </font>
    </td>
    <td width="50%">
      <span style="font-size:14px;"><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;">$%%=v(@Monthly_Charge__c)=%%</span></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="50%">
      <b>
        <span style="font-size:14px;"><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;">Mobile calling charge</span></span>
      </b>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span style="font-size:14px;"><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;">$%%=v(@Mobile_Calling_Charge__c)=%%</span></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="50%">
      <b>
        <span style="font-size:14px;"><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;">International calling charge</span></span>
      </b>
    </td>
    <td width="50%">
      <span style="font-size:14px;"><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;">%%=v(@International_Calling_Charge__c)=%%</span></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  %%[
  endif  
  next @i 
  else 
  endif ]%%
  
</table>
```

**Current output below**

[image]

**Desired output**

[image]

Comment: What happens when you test? Is there an error thrown or is it displayed incorrectly? In any case, please, let us know in more detail what by either copy-pasting the error message or attaching a screenshot

Comment: From what you describe, it's not clear what is going wrong and we cannot really help. Some general advice that will a) help you, and b) help us help you: Paste your code into `ampscript.io` to check syntax; The only error I get there is harmless, but probably something you want to fix (variable `@Medical_Dependency_Voice__c` is not defined); move away from using needless open / close markers `%%[` , `]%%` - e.g. the bottom of your code has 8 where you need 2; use indentation; for us to help: isolate the issue, cut usecase specific stuff; specify the expected behavior and the actual behavior;

Comment: updated my question